Insecure Deserialization in C# (.NET) using NewtonsoftJson
I am working on a Web API that needs to call a 3rd party Web API to achieve some features. That 3rd party's API's design is sort of a "God API" such that it takes a generic object type to allow that single API to be used for MANY different features with MANY different settings (900+). I've setup a minimal example in the first commit of this repo
(the TestRequests.http file can be used in Rider IDE's HTTP client plugin or you can just copy it into something similar like postman)
Despite me setting TypeNameHandling.None, the security reviewers at my company still think that having the object type anywhere in the API contract is vulnerable to Insecure Deserialization. They have not yet provided a concrete demo showing a successful exploit, but they still think we need to avoid any chance of one. Therefore they want me to specify strict types in all API contracts.
In the first commit I tried making a base abstract class but .NET gives "Could not create an instance of type DeserializationDemo.BaseSetting. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated."
So I then used a Custom ModelBinder in the second commit and it seems to work. However it requires casting to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. And that is the same type that DemoContract1 seems to get de-serialized to anyways when I check with a debugger. So wouldn't it be suspect to the same (hypothetical) vulnerabilities?

The only alternative I see is to avoid polymorphic types all together. To make a different endpoint, each with its own strict type, for each of the 900+ features.
My questions for the community are:

Is setting TypeNameHandling.None not enough to avoid Insecure Deserialization?
Are there any alternatives to the Custom ModelBinder that could allow me to be more strict on allowed types but wouldn't result in de-serializing to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject?


Welcome to the community, but I'm afraid this is a pure programming question...
